# Why are there no holomorphic quadratic differentials on a complex torus?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, teichmueller-theory

It is well-known that the space or *strata* $\mathcal{Q}(\emptyset)$ of quadratic differentials with no poles or zeros on a genus 1 surface is empty (this is one of the four exceptions to a theorem of Smilie and Masur in Teichmuller theory which says those strata are nonempty).

My silly question is, for $dz$ the standard/classical holomorphic differential on a complex torus $T=\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$, why is $w=(dz)^2$ not an example of a holomorphic quadratic differential on $T$?

Comment: It is indeed a nowhere-zero holomorphic quadratic differential.

Comment: Presumably you missed the point in their theorem where they're looking at the moduli space of quadratic differentials that are *not* globally the square of a holomorphic differential.